# JSON.stringify not converting array.object correctly

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a problem with JSON.stringify

I'm trying to pull all the meta tags out of the page and pass them to a firefox worker file to  work through them and to return back an object.

So my code previously worked when I didn't have a worker running the issue has only cropped up when I have moved to using worker file (for reasons I can't go into I need to use a worker!)

So previously I would get all the meta tags using

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
```

then I could loop through the metas object by using

```
for (var index in metas){
  var currentMeta = metas[index];
//(and so on, this code worked perfectly)
```

The problem occurs when I move to the external worker file scenario.
What happens is I pull the meta tags out as normal, and then I use JSON.stringify to something that I can push to the worker.

After all that intro blab, here is the root of my problem:
Take for example that I land on a page with the following code within the html

```
<meta content="width=1024" name="viewport">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content="Mozilla Hacks – the Web developer blog" name="title">
```

If I run the following code I get an array

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
```

returns an array 3 elements

```
[meta, meta, meta]
```

If I stringify it using:

```
var jsonMetas = JSON.stringify(metas);
```

I would expect to jsonMetas to hold something like:

```
{"0":{"content":"width=1024","name":"viewport"},"1":{"charset":"UTF-8"},"2":{"content":"Mozilla Hacks - the web developer blog","name":"title"} }
```

However when I look at the jsonMetas object I see this returned:

```
{"0":{"constructor":{}},"1":{"constructor":{}},"2":{"constructor":{}}}
```

Huh?????

I'm not that good at JavaScript, so could you please explaining (in very small words :) ) what is going on?

Why does the stringify call return the unusually structured object?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/M69DZ/):

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < metas[i].attributes.length; j++) {
        var att = metas[i].attributes[j];
        obj[att.name] = att.value;
    }
    arr.push(obj);
}

var jsonMetas = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(jsonMetas);​
```

results in:

```
[
    {
        "http-equiv": "content-type",
        "content": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    {
        "content": "width=1024",
        "name": "viewport"
    },
    {
        "charset": "UTF-8"
    },
    {
        "content": "Mozilla Hacks – the Web developer blog",
        "name": "title"
    }
]
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Cheers Darin, it works perfectly :) As a matter of interest, why was my code creating an unusual object structure?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that *document.getElementsByTagName* doesn't return JSON, it returns XML.  So, you'd need to use something like this to get your desired output:

```
var jsonMetas = [];
for (i=0 ; i<metas.length ; i++) {
    var thisMeta = {};
    for (j=0 ; j<metas[i].attributes.length ; j++) {
        thisMeta[metas[i].attributes[j].name] = metas[i].attributes[j].value;
    }
    jsonMetas.push(thisMeta);
}
```

Output of JSON.stringify(jsonMetas) for this page:

> "[{"name":"relativepagescore","content":"0"},{"name":"title","content":"javascript - JSON.stringify not converting array.object correctly - Stack Overflow"}]"

Comment: It returns dom objects not XML

Comment: @meandmycode Um, actually it returns JSON.  See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Nope, getElementsByTagName returns DOM objects, not XML or JSON.. those things have absolutely nothing to do with this layer, for example.. I could well have created and populated the document from createElement etc.. no XML or JSON in sight.

Comment: Also, you need to grow up, if you think visiting all of my questions and answers and down voting them makes a difference.. I'm not here for the numbers.

Comment: @meandmycode as long as we're talking about what people "need to do", you need to learn to read.  Does my answer return JSON or does it not?  The whole point of this question is that intermediate steps are needed to convert a DOM object into JSON.

Comment: @meandmycode also should be noted that my answer is virtually identical to the one the Op accepted.  It's not that I care about rep, it's that I don't suffer fools lightly.

Comment: "The reason is that document.getElementsByTagName doesn't return JSON, it returns XML" .. nope, I think you need to learn to read, your own words no less.

Comment: @meandmycode this isn't really a debate, bro.  The code I wrote is functioning code.  You can copy/paste it into any web page and it will return the page's meta tags as JSON.  End of story.

Comment: It's certainly not functional, and it poorly educates.. bro

Comment: @meandmycode Ah, so you're an educator; how very noble of you!  Looks like I got you all wrong.  Clown.

Comment: @dbaseman Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. You are right in saying that you answer is almost identical to Darin. I had checked both answers and bot suited my needs, I should have thanked you a little bit eariler Cheers :)