# looking for js library for formatting string to match json requirments

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, special-characters

I'm using jQuery ajax to send updates from the client's browser to my server,
I noticed that there is some characters that JSON doesn't support,
and in order to send them, i need to add additional \ in front of each.

This characters are well documented at json.com:

[image: jsonStrings]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/string.gif))</sub>

I'm not so good at javascripting (i'm new in this area),
So i wonder if there is any already made function that takes a string and formats it to fit this requirement?

iv'e searched the web but couldn't find any javascript solution for this..

Thanks in advance,
Eitan.

Comment: What do you mean by "some characters JSON.stringify does not like"? `JSON.stringify` converts an object to a JSON string. It may contain `\uHHHH` (where `H`s are hexadecimal numbers), but that is by design.

Comment: What about URI encoding, or am I off my rocker?

Comment: Would this Stackoverflow post help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868922/json-stringify-not-converting-array-object-correctly

Comment: Why do you need to add another `\`? Please provide an example of what you have and what you want to reach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript

Comment: @karthikr - not really, it's another issue.. thanks anyway.

Comment: @Lekensteyn - what do you mean?
you want me to supply some source code?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind - it adds escape to the standart special chars, but what about the unicode chars?..

Comment: Why do you need to escape regular unicode characters?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind - not the regular, but the unicode control characters (from \u0000 to \u001F)

Comment: @user1179861 `JSON.stringify("\01") == '"\\u0001"'` (displayed as `\u0001`) on Firefox 15.0.1. What else would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! i spent too much time on this @$!

I found that the JSON.stringify indeed take care of the special characters.
The problem was in the way that i used to structure the data...
I did it like:

```
blah = JSON.stringify( { a: "1" } );
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "page.aspx/MethodName",
         data: "{ paramName: '" + blah + "'}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json"});
```

To fix this, i just did:

```
//nesting the param name in the data structure passed to stringify:
blah = JSON.stringify( { paramName : { a: "1" } } ); 
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "page.aspx/MethodName",
             data: blah,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json"});
```

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me solve this..